# ¿Como sumar columnas de una Tabla HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Tan solo quisiera saber como poder sumarle las columnas, ya que soy nuevo y desearía saber como aplicarlo con java script.

Esta es mi función:

```html
<table id="tabla" class="table" style="width:51%;">   
    
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>letras</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <Th>E</Th>
         <Th>F</Th>
          <Th>H</Th>
      </tr>
       <tr>
    <td id="f1">a</td>
    <td id="f2" >1</td>
    <td id="f2">2</td>
    <td id="f2">3</td>
    <td id="f2">4</td>
    <td id="f2">5</td>
    <td id="f2">6</td>
    <td id="f2">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td id="f1">b</td>
    <td id="f2">1</td>
    <td id="f2">2</td>
    <td id="f2">3</td>
    <td id="f2">4</td>
    <td id="f2">5</td>
    <td id="f2">6</td>
    <td id="f2">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>  
    <td id="f1">c</td>
    <td id="f2">1</td>
    <td id="f2">2</td>
    <td id="f2">3</td>
    <td id="f2">4</td>
    <td id="f2">5</td>
    <td id="f2">6</td>
    <td id="f2">7</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td >su total:</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
     </tr>
     
     </thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: Ya te dieron la respuesta, solo quiero recalcar algo en tu codigo, cuando uses el **id** este tiene que ser un identificador unico, no puedes repetir id para nombrar mas de un elemento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar Jquery para recorrer las filas e ir acumulando la cantidad por columna

Esta es mi función:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 CalcularTotal();

});
function CalcularTotal()
{
var totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
 var $filas= $("#tabla tr:not('.total, .encabezado')");

  $filas.each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
      if (i != 0)
        totals[i - 1] += parseInt($(this).html());
    });
  });
  $(".total td").each(function(i) {
    if (i != 0)
      $(this).html(totals[i - 1]);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla" class="table" style="width:51%;">

  <thead>
    <tr class="encabezado">
      <th>letras</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>H</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="f1">a</td>
      <td id="f2">1</td>
      <td id="f2">2</td>
      <td id="f2">3</td>
      <td id="f2">4</td>
      <td id="f2">5</td>
      <td id="f2">6</td>
      <td id="f2">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="f1">b</td>
      <td id="f2">1</td>
      <td id="f2">2</td>
      <td id="f2">3</td>
      <td id="f2">4</td>
      <td id="f2">5</td>
      <td id="f2">6</td>
      <td id="f2">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="f1">c</td>
      <td id="f2">1</td>
      <td id="f2">2</td>
      <td id="f2">3</td>
      <td id="f2">4</td>
      <td id="f2">5</td>
      <td id="f2">6</td>
      <td id="f2">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="total">
      <td>su total:</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>

  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado!

Comment: Una pregunta @Byron: cuando edito un numero de la fila, no se actualiza la tabla... como hago para que eso funcione?

Comment: @ReinosRic actualice el codigo para encapsular el codigfo en un metodo, cada vez que actualiza la tabla deberias invocar el metodo `CalcularTotal();`

Answer (score 3):

## Explicación

Ya que estás comenzando por este camino del HTML te recomiendo aprender acerca de los Query Selectors y como se pueden usar, en este caso usé una agrupación por clase por cada columna y su correspondiente total.

En el código hice primero una iteración sobre todos los elementos que pertenecen a la clase Total y además de eso con más de 1 clase asignada, esta segunda clase la usaremos para identificar todas las columnas correspondientes a sumar.

Hacemos el segundo QuerySelector y este nos retornará todos los TD pertenecientes a la clase Columna+letra convertirá su contenido de string a entero y lo sumará en una variable.

finalmente esta suma la establecerá a la celda que está iterando el primer for.

Espero que sea de ayuda mi respuesta, saludos.

## Codigo

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.Total').forEach(function (total) {
        if (total.classList.length > 1) {
            var letra = total.classList[1];
            var suma = 0;
            document.querySelectorAll('.Columna' + letra).forEach(function (celda) {
                var valor = parseInt(celda.innerHTML);
                suma += valor;
            });
            total.innerHTML = suma;
        }
    });
```

```html
<table id="tabla" class="table" style="width:51%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>letras</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <Th>E</Th>
            <Th>F</Th>
            <Th>H</Th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ColumnaLetra">a</td>
            <td class="ColumnaA">1</td>
            <td class="ColumnaB">2</td>
            <td class="ColumnaC">3</td>
            <td class="ColumnaD">4</td>
            <td class="ColumnaE">5</td>
            <td class="ColumnaF">6</td>
            <td class="ColumnaG">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ColumnaLetra">b</td>
            <td class="ColumnaA">1</td>
            <td class="ColumnaB">2</td>
            <td class="ColumnaC">3</td>
            <td class="ColumnaD">4</td>
            <td class="ColumnaE">5</td>
            <td class="ColumnaF">6</td>
            <td class="ColumnaG">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ColumnaLetra">c</td>
            <td class="ColumnaA">1</td>
            <td class="ColumnaB">2</td>
            <td class="ColumnaC">3</td>
            <td class="ColumnaD">4</td>
            <td class="ColumnaE">5</td>
            <td class="ColumnaF">6</td>
            <td class="ColumnaG">7</td>
        </tr>

        

        <tr>
            <td class="Total">Su total</td>
            <td class="Total A"></td>
            <td class="Total B"></td>
            <td class="Total C"></td>
            <td class="Total D"></td>
            <td class="Total E"></td>
            <td class="Total F"></td>
            <td class="Total G"></td>
        </tr>

    </thead>
</table>
```

## Referencias

Te invito a que te documentes con la siguiente referencia:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Una forma rápida es usar Jquery, incluyelo en el `<head>`:

agregamos unas `class` a los `<tr>` para seleccionarlos mas rapido. El codigo quedaria:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var totalA=0;
        var totalB=0;
        //repetir por columna, o usa un array
        $('.suma').map(function(k,v){
            totalA=totalA+parseInt($(this).children('td:eq(1)').text());
            totalB=totalB+parseInt($(this).children('td:eq(2)').text());
            //repetir por columna o llena un array
        })
        $('.total').children('td:eq(1)').text(totalA);
        $('.total').children('td:eq(2)').text(totalB);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tabla" class="table" style="width:51%;">       
<thead>
<tr>
<th>letras</th>
<th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <Th>E</Th>
     <Th>F</Th>
      <Th>H</Th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr class="suma">
<td id="f1">a</td>
<td id="f2" >1</td>
<td id="f2">2</td>
<td id="f2">3</td>
<td id="f2">4</td>
<td id="f2">5</td>
<td id="f2">6</td>
<td id="f2">7</td>
</tr>

<tr class="suma">
<td id="f1">b</td>
<td id="f2">1</td>
<td id="f2">2</td>
<td id="f2">3</td>
<td id="f2">4</td>
<td id="f2">5</td>
<td id="f2">6</td>
<td id="f2">7</td>
</tr>

<tr class="suma">  
<td id="f1">c</td>
<td id="f2">1</td>
<td id="f2">2</td>
<td id="f2">3</td>
<td id="f2">4</td>
<td id="f2">5</td>
<td id="f2">6</td>
<td id="f2">7</td>
</tr>

 <tr class="total">
  <td >su total:</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
 </tr>

 </thead>
```